# list all artifacts in a repository on JFrog Artifactory

Tags: curl, artifactory

I'm new to the Artifactory. Currently I'm working on a project to list all the artifacts in a repository.

Artifactory version:4.1.3 Pro (turned off the cert verification)

```
curl -u uname:password -X POST -k https://artifactory.xxxx.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({"repo":"war"}).include("name","repo","path","size").sort({"$desc":["size"]}).limit(10)"


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /artifactory/api/search/aql was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at artifactory.xxxx.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

It's throwing an error(Bad request). Try to list out the artifacts in the following repos war,war-dev,war-release,webapp,webapp-dev(get the list of repos from Artifactory database and http request).

Tried to list out the artifacts using REST calls anonymously,But there are no logs in `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/request_trace.log $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/request.log`

Get the list of repos from artdb(Artifactory database) and artifactory url. listed repos are different from one to other. Which one is correct?

Listed so many repos

```
mysql> select distinct(repo) from nodes;
| war                               |
| war-dev                           |
| war-release                       |

https://artifactory.xxxx.com/artifactory/repo/
webapp/                                                       
webapp-dev/
```

Can someone help to find out the list of artifacts in repo Please. Thank you!

Comment: If you provide the AQL inline and get unsupported media exception, you can resolve that by adding -H "Content-Type: text/plain".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AQL is the way to go. And your query is *almost* good (you forgot the `$match` for all the repos starting with `war` or `web`. The problem is curl. If you want to write the query string in the command line you need to escape all the inner `"` and `$`. Here's the working query:

```
curl -u uname:password -X POST -k https://artifactory.xxxx.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"file\",\"\$or\":[{\"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"war*\"}, \"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"web*\"} }]}).include(\"name\",\"repo\",\"path\",\"size\").sort({\"\$desc\": [\"size\"]}).limit(10)"
```

Now, this is hell. Instead, consider writing the query in a text file and passing it with `-d @filename.aql`. In this case you don't need all the escaping and the query will look like:

```
items.find({
  "type" : "file",
  "$or":[{
    "repo" : {"$match" : "war*"}, 
    "repo" : {"$match" : "web*"} }]})
  .include("name","repo","path","size")
  .sort({"$desc": ["size"]})
  .limit(10)
```

Comment: Hi @JBaruch. I've tried with your suggestion, But there is no luck.  It looks like some issue with the artifactory itself.

Comment: Hi @JBaruch. I've tried with your suggestion, But there is no luck.  It looks like some issue with the artifactory itself. I've updated curl command with -k (Added to skip cert verification). I guess it's unable to reach artifactory.

$curl -u pkjogi:Ilikemyself@123 -X POST -k https://artifactory.clearslideng.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"file\",\"\$or\":[{\"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"war*\"}, \"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"web*\"} }]}).include(\"name\",\"repo\",\"path\",\"size\").sort({\"\$desc\": [\"size\"]}).limit(10)"

Comment: Let's do something simple. Execute [a system ping request](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemHealthPing) from curl. If it fails, ask a new question with the output of curl with `-vv` flag.

Comment: Able to connect to the server,But it looks like issue with AQL. 
 
  Connected to artifactory.xxx.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
  ....................................................
  GET /artifactory/api/search/aql HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic sdifjdsmclkxzmsqwdspxzzfjla==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: artifactory.xxxx.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 02 Apr 2016 16:21:00 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon)

Comment: Hi! It has been al long time since this was asked, but: If I use the call as given I get an "Unsupported Media Type" error. Any idea?

Comment: @eventhorizon You have to supply the Content-Type header, i.e. `-H "content-type: text/plain"`

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked when I used Content-Type text/plain instead of application/json, i.e.

```
curl -u uname -X POST http://host:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -H "content-type: text/plain" -d @filename.aql
```

Comment: I would have never guessed this. Thanks. `    "status" : 415,
    "message" : "Unsupported Media Type"` in case anyone is doing a text search on this page.

Answer (score 3):

This is also working for me. Either you can write the command as specified by @JBaruch or you can run the JSON AQL file.

`curl -u uname -X POST http://host:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -H "content-type: application/json" -d @filename.aql`