# Download multiple files from the artifactory repo using powershell

Tags: powershell, artifactory, powershell-4.0

I was trying to write a powershell script which downloads multiple files from my artifactory repo. I could use some kind of logic as below by passing file names.

```
$files = @("test1.zip", "test.zip") 

foreach($file in $files)
{
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$artifactory_url/$file" -OutFile "D:\download\$file"
}
```

But, Is there any way to download all the files with out passing names? I tried with wildcards like (*zip) but, looks like Invoke-webrequest isn't accepting the wildcards. And found no luck with Start-bittransfer cmdlet as well as described in article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/17/use-powershell-3-0-to-easily-download-60-spanned-files .

I was able to pull up list of files in the repo using below command

```
((Invoke-WebRequest $url).links | Where href -match "zip$").href
```

How can I use this command to download the files? Is there any better way to download multiple files from the artifactory repo or http endpoint? I have to perform this action on multiple servers. So, I was not looking at usage of jfrog cli.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `$file = ((Invoke-WebRequest $url).links ...`, then `foreach($file in $files)`?

Comment: I would expect that you need to [enumerate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36364859/1630171) the artifacts and then download them individually.

Comment: @gms0ulman yes, I tried by using below code
 
invoke-webrequest “$url”|select -exp links|where{$_.href -like "*.zip"}|select -exp href|foreach{start-bitstransfer $_ C:/users/my_home}
But, it didn't worked for me.

Comment: any reason you cannot use jfrog cli? if you are indeed stuck with powershell, you should first do an AQL search to retrieve the list of files, and then enumerate on it like you are doing now

Answer (score 4):

You may be missing the credentials to be sent with the request.

If you are using an Artifactory Key you could use the WebClient object like the following -

```
 #example Artifactory url
 $artifactory_url = "https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/"
 #example Artifactory Key
 $ArtifactoryKey = "AKCp2VpEfLuMVkxpmH9rSiZT3RPoWCucL8kEiq4SjbEuuuCFdNf5t5E6dom32TCE3efy2RCyg" 

 $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 $wc.Headers.Add("X-JFrog-Art-Api", $ArtifactoryKey)
 $files = @("test1.zip", "test.zip") 
 try {
   foreach($file in $files) {
     $wc.DownloadFile("$artifactory_url/$file", "D:\download\$file")
   }
 }
 catch {
    $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine("Error while Trying to download Artifacts.")
    $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine($_.Exception.Message)
    exit
 }
```